# Typescript+AngularJS+Webpack modules without default export

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, bootstrap-ui

I'm using Webpack to bundle AngularJS with Typescript (with the default setup suggested [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/)) and I cannot include modules that do not have default exports, such as ui-bootstrap. Modules such as ui-router do not have such problem since their typings mention a default export.

JS code works:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import router from 'angular-ui-router';
import uibootstrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';

angular.module('app', [uirouter, uibootstrap]);
```

However the same code in Typescript (target: es6, module: es6, all settings same as those mentioned in webpack guide) drops error:

> Module "node_modules/@types/angular-ui-bootstrap/index" has no default export.

Using `angular.module('app', [uirouter, 'ui.bootstrap']);` instead throws a 'ui.bootstrap' not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems using a simple `import 'angular-ui-router'` works.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to true in your `tsconfig.json` to continue importing `import uibootstrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';` as if `angular-ui-bootstrap` had a default export.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

Comment: This seems like the right solution, but it still did not import the library, making "ui.route" include in my angular module non-functional.